# .animate() works fine once, but not twice

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

First of all thanks for reading and sorry for my english.

I am trying to make a dynamic menu where you click the icon and then the field (li) selected animates to get a bigger width. When I click the field it animates perfectly and gets the width AND it changes its class from "unselected" to "selected". Then, when I click it again, it doesn't get its initial width.

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("li.unselected").on("click",expand);
    $("li.selected").on("click",reduce);

    function expand(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: '150px'
        });
        $(this).removeClass("unselected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    }

    function reduce(){
        $(this).animate({
            width: '30px'
        });
        $(this).removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("unselected");
    }
});
```

PD: I've already checked the HTML code as it's working and the class perfectly changes from "unselected" to "selected", but it doesn't work the other way around.

Comment: $(document).on("click", "li.selected", reduce);

Comment: @KaiQing It expands and immediately reduces again :(

Answer (score 2):

If you change your listeners to be bound to document it should work fine:

```
$(document).on("click","li.unselected", expand);
$(document).on("click","li.selected", reduce);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b5PB2/1/

You can also manage this with css transitions:
http://jsfiddle.net/b5PB2/

```
//html    
<ul class="list">
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Something Else</li>
</ul>

//css
.list li{
    width:30px;
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#d1d1d1;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    transition: width 0.5s linear;
}

.list li.selected{
   width:150px;
   transition: width 0.5s linear;
}

//basic jquery listener to toggle class
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list li').on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
});
```

side note - I use sass with autoprefixer, so transition is automatically generated into the various needs for things like webkit, etc. You would need to look up the prefixes needed for css transitions to work in all browsers.